# produce a network graph from call records in neo4j- Newbie

Tags: neo4j

in Neo4J I am trying to visualize a small amount of calls taken from a csv file ( fake numbers sample below):

```
A,B
1,4
1,5
1,2
2,7
2,9
2,11
3,15
```

I am dealing with each column (A,B) as phone numbers would be the nodes and the presence of a call between them ( A to B ) is the relationship

ideally the graph produced should show multiple relationships between 
the nodes (e.g.:node with value 1 would have three connections to other nodes and one of these is node 2 with value 2 that has another three connections,finally node with value 3 would have a connection but be separate)

the code i am trying

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:blahblahblah.csv" AS row
CREATE (A:phone {number: row.A})
CREATE (B:phone {number: row.B})
WITH A as a MATCH (a)-[:CALLED*]-(m)
RETURN a,m
```

and obviously its producing repeated nodes and only single relationships with no 2nd level arrows..

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be most efficient:

```
create constraint on (p:phone) assert p.number is unique;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:blahblahblah.csv" AS row
with distinct row.A as value
MERGE (:phone {number: value});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:blahblahblah.csv" AS row
with distinct row.B as value
MERGE (:phone {number: value});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:blahblahblah.csv" AS row
MATCH (A:phone {number: row.A})
MATCH (B:phone {number: row.B})
MERGE (A)-[r:CALLED]->(B) 
  ON CREATE SET r.count = 1 
  ON MATCH SET r.count = r.count + 1;
```

Not really sure what you want to query though?
E.g.

```
MATCH (a:phone)-[r:CALLED]->(b)
RETURN a, sum(r.count) as calls
ORDER BY calls DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: i figured it out...  I tried this 
 MATCH (a:phone)-[r:CALLED]->(b)
 RETURN a,b, sum(r.count) as calls
 ORDER BY calls DESC LIMIT 10; 
It actually provided the results showing both A and B party. 
I also tried 
 MATCH (n)-[r:CALLED]->(b)
 WITH n,b, count(r) as rel_cnt
 WHERE rel_cnt > 1
 RETURN n; 
to get those with more than 1 connection ...thanks Michael,